# How to draw analyzer from audio url?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

How to draw analyzer from audio url?

I am getting the audio url (`http://api.server.com/uploads/files/ecae64b511b1266fa3930731ec379d2dcdcc7546.wav`) from an API server. I want to draw this sound on canvas, following function works on the blob object (recorded from suer), but it does not work with the url:

```
$window.AudioContext = $window.AudioContext || $window.webkitAudioContext;
vm.audioContext = new AudioContext();

function gotStream(stream) {
  vm.inputPoint = vm.audioContext.createGain();
  vm.realAudioInput = vm.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  vm.audioInput = vm.realAudioInput;
  vm.audioInput.connect(vm.inputPoint);

  // audioInput = convertToMono( input );

  vm.analyserNode = vm.audioContext.createAnalyser();
  vm.analyserNode.fftSize = 2048;
  vm.inputPoint.connect(vm.analyserNode);
  vm.audioRecorder = new Recorder(vm.inputPoint);

  var zeroGain = vm.audioContext.createGain();
  zeroGain.gain.value = 0.0;
  vm.inputPoint.connect(zeroGain);
  zeroGain.connect(vm.audioContext.destination);
  updateAnalysers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a CORS issue if the file is from a different origin from the code.  If you don't fix this, MediaStreamSource will probably just output zeroes.